# Add List Item to Remote Sharepoint 2007 using Powershell

Tags: web-services, powershell, sharepoint-2007

I am attempting to automatically add records to a list in Sharepoint. I am following along in this post

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/06/24/using-new-webserviceproxy-to-get-modify-and-add-items-to-a-list-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx

but keep receiving an error.

Code to date:

```
$packet = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::Parse(@"
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="1">
 <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
  <Field Name="Checked At">2006-1-11T09:15:30Z</Field>
  <Field Name="Cold">0</Field>
  <Field Name="Inbox">0</Field>
 </Method>
</Batch>
"@).Root;
$uri = "http://.../_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
$listName = "Daily Check";
$lists = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential;
$lists.UpdateListItems($listName,$packet);
```

This keeps returning the error:

```
Exception calling "UpdateListItems" with "2" argument(s): "Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown."
At line:14 char:1
+ $lists.UpdateListItems($listName,$packet);
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SoapException
```

There doesn't seem to be much other information in the error message.

Output from `$lists`

```
SoapVersion                          : Default
AllowAutoRedirect                    : False
CookieContainer                      : 
ClientCertificates                   : {}
EnableDecompression                  : False
UserAgent                            : Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.0)
Proxy                                : 
UnsafeAuthenticatedConnectionSharing : False
Credentials                          : System.Net.SystemNetworkCredential
UseDefaultCredentials                : True
ConnectionGroupName                  : 
PreAuthenticate                      : False
Url                                  : http:// ... /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
RequestEncoding                      : 
Timeout                              : 100000
Site                                 : 
Container                            :
```

## Update

It appears that read methods are OK, but write is causing the error. Unfortunately, there just isn't enough information about the error to action it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine except that you are sending the name of the list in parameter 1 to updatelistitems. We have similar code, but we use the listid in the first parameter.

To get the id of the list from the name of the list, do the following.

```
$listidandviewid = $lists.getlistandview($listname, "")
$listid = $listandviewid.childnodes.item(0).name
```

if you want the viewid as well you can also use.

```
$viewid = $listandviewid.childnodes.item(1).name
```

Then finally use the listid

```
$lists.UpdateListItems($listid,$packet);
```

Hope it works out for you!

Comment: When I try adding the call to `GetListAndView` I'm getting the same error. This leads me to believe that the error is in the way the connection is formed.

Comment: Please try to output the value of $lists. That will give you an indication if you have the Connection setup or not.

Comment: That seems to be reasonable as well. I also passed it through get-members just to ensure there was sensible stuff (both GetListAndView and UpdateListItems are present)

Comment: It's correct, I've just annonimized it. I have cut and paste it back into the browser a couple of times just to be sure.